# Get value from xxx.plist to Build Settings in Target

Tags: ios, xcode, plist

I have created a custom plist named as test.plist in Supporting Files folder. In that i stored App product name and App version number.

Now, how could i get product name from test.plist for PRODUCT NAME in Build Settings in Target.

I can get values from user defined build settings. But i don't want that.

**Note**: *I need to store product name in test.plist only. And others can access the value from this file*.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score -1):

you can read the values from the plist in main bundle, put below code in viewDidLoad , method, Please note that all files in main bundle are read only if you want to write any data to plist then you have to copy it to app's document directory

```
NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@”test” ofType:@”plist”];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:bundle];
NSString *productName = [dict objectForKey:@"ProductName"];
NSString * appVersion = [dict objectForKey:@"AppVersion"];
```

Another way is to read app properties

```
NSString *appName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
NSString appVersion = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Version %@ (%@)", [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"], kRevisionNumber];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response. Here you told about read values from test.plist. That's fine. But how can i use these values in Build Settings in Target file.

Comment: see my second answer it reads values from project's info.plist

Comment: Yeah, we can read it. But how can i access from Build Settings in Target ?